# Finding gap between two data outputs

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i'm having this issue when I need to find the gap between two avg salaries of total employees,
Meaning all the employees working on a project AND all the employees are not working on a project. 
(Or Belongs to the a project if you will)

here's the relevant tables :

```
create table employee (
    eid numeric(5,0),
    ename varchar(30),
    salary integer,
    did numeric(3,0),
    classification integer,
    primary key(eid),
    foreign key(did)references department
);

create table onproject(
    pid numeric(3,0),
    eid numeric(5,0),
    fdate date,
    primary key(pid,eid),
    foreign key (eid) references employee,
    foreign key (pid) references project
);
```

Please keep in mind that I CANNOT change the way the tables are written.
My idea was to create AVG for those employees who are not currently belong to any project and vise versa
I have managed to get this :

```
select count(employee.eid),avg(salary) 
from employee
where employee.eid not in select onproject.eid from onproject
```

but not much after that unfortunately

Comment: First, figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then look at `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: No idea what that meant...

Comment: Are you using mysql OR postgresql

Comment: postgresql <--- this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a left join of `employee` to `onproject` and then with conditional aggregation:

```
select
  avg(case when t.ison is not null then t.salary end) - 
  avg(case when t.ison is null then t.salary end) gap
from (  
  select e.eid, e.salary, max(o.eid) ison 
  from employee e left join onproject o
  on o.eid = e.eid
  group by e.eid, e.salary
) t
```

Comment: See that's the thing ,
they can work on 2 or even 3 project at the same time

P.S (Sorry I forgot to mention clearly its very important)

Comment: First of all I wanted to thank you! 
is it okay if you explain what you did here :  avg(case when t.ison is not null then t.salary end) - 
  avg(case when t.ison is null then t.salary end) gap

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed as follows:

```
select
    avg(salary) filter(where has_project = 1) avg_salary_on_project
    avg(salary) filter(where has_project = 0) avg_salary_not_on_project
from (
    select 
        eid,
        salary,
        case when exists (select 1 from onproject o where o.eid = e.eid) 
            then 1
            else 0
        end has_project
    from employee e
) t
```

The inner query makes use of an inline subquery to identify whether each employee belong to at least one project. This produces a boolean column (`0/1`) called `has_project`. The outer query does conditional average using that column.